# Adding Countdown Timer Using Checkout Extensibility in Shopify App

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am using Shopify CLI 3. I have made a count down Timer but there is a issue, The timer is working fine but when I reload the page or go to the next step of checkout, the timer restarts I am storing data in session storage but that doesn't seem to be working I have also tried to store data in cookie, local storage and even cache storage but none of them seem to work.

Can some one guide me how to accomplish this task?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  render,
  BlockStack,
  Text,
  useSettings,
  View
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {

  const calculateEndTime = (timer) => {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    const endTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + timer * 60000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds

    return endTime;
  };

  const getRemainingTimeInSeconds = (endTime) => {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    const remainingTimeInSeconds = Math.floor((endTime - currentTime) / 1000);

    return remainingTimeInSeconds >= 0 ? remainingTimeInSeconds : 0;
  };

  const setCookie = (name, value, days) => {
    const expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setTime(expirationDate.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${expirationDate.toUTCString()}; path=/`;
  };

  const getCookie = (name) => {
    const cookieName = `${name}=`;
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      let cookie = cookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(cookieName.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }

    return '';
  };

  const deleteCookie = (name) => {
    document.cookie = `${name}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`;
  };

  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedEndTime = getCookie('endTime');
    let endTime;

    if (storedEndTime) {
      endTime = new Date(storedEndTime);

      // If the stored end time has already passed, clear it and recalculate the end time
      if (endTime <= new Date()) {
        deleteCookie('endTime');
        endTime = calculateEndTime(isNaN(timer) ? +timer : timer); // Set the timer to 15 minutes
      }
    } else {
      endTime = calculateEndTime(isNaN(timer) ? +timer : timer); // Set the timer to 15 minutes
      setCookie('endTime', endTime.toUTCString(), 1);
    }

    setSeconds(getRemainingTimeInSeconds(endTime));

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prevSeconds) => {
        if (prevSeconds <= 0) {
          clearInterval(interval); // Stop the timer
          deleteCookie('endTime');
          return 0;
        }
        return prevSeconds - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  const formattedTime = React.useMemo(() => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${remainingSeconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }, [seconds]);

  return (
    <BlockStack>
      <View>
          <Text>
            {formattedTime}
          </Text>
      </View>
    </BlockStack>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Shopify Plus store, I recommend you update the checkout layout option from three-page checkout to one-page checkout. Which is available in `Settings > Checkout > Checkout 1 > Customize`

[image]

For your countdown timer session storage issue, I've added one JS below, which is working for me. I hope it will work for you.

```js
        const COUNTER_KEY = 'my-counter';
        function countDown(i, callback) {
          //callback = callback || function(){};
          timer = setInterval(function() {
            minutes = parseInt(i / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(i % 60, 10);
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
            document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "Time left " + "0:" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            if ((i--) > 0) {
              window.sessionStorage.setItem(COUNTER_KEY, i);
              } else {
              window.sessionStorage.removeItem(COUNTER_KEY);
              clearInterval(timer);
              callback();
              }
            }, 1000);
          }
        window.onload = function() {
          var countDownTime = window.sessionStorage.getItem(COUNTER_KEY) || 600; 
// 600 for 10min, 60 for 1min
          countDown(countDownTime, function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
          };
```

```html
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
```